# HTML5 File System Info Bar Not Responding In Kiosk Mode

Tags: javascript, html, chromium, kiosk, html5-filesystem

I am creating an application that runs in chromium portable in full screen with the --kiosk flag.  It is written in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.  I am also using the HTML5 File System to store some large sets of data.  The application opens up in full screen, and the info bar to request permanent storage pops up.

The problem is that, while running in kiosk mode, you cannot select either "OK" or "Cancel" to the file system's request to store data.  You can only close the info bar with the "X".  This results in the file system not getting any kind of quota and the application fails.

So is there a way to have unlimited storage for an application running from "file:///"?  I have tried using --unlimited-storage but it doesn't seem to work for a webpage.

Is there a way to open up in full screen without using --kiosk?  Any other work arounds or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Chromium Portable are you using?  I had a similar issue awhile back, but I don't have the same problem in the newer versions.  I am using the latest version as of now which is Chromium Portable 30.0.1599.10 (released on 2013-08-21).

Comment: I was using a much older version.  Got the new one and it worked! Thanks for the advice!